# How to format the date string according to the country in angular?

Tags: angularjs, date, date-format, angular-translate, angular-date-format

I had the following code where i get the data from JSON response. I want to change the date string format w.r.t to country locale. I'm using angular-translate for translations and added all the strings in respective locale json file. For example i want to add the date format (dd/mm/year) for es_ES(spanish) locale  and (mm/dd/year) for en_US. Can i add the date format by any chance in the Json file or how can i add a filter to format in markup itself? Is it possible at all?

```
//Sample Html markup
<tr ng-repeat="data in data.list">
<td>{{data.originalDate}}</td>
<td>{{data.expiryDate}}</td>
</tr>          

//sampleJsonResponse
{
"data": [
"{originalDate:\"09/30/2017\",expiryDate:\"10/30/2018\"}"
 ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [sugar.js](https://sugarjs.com/) javascript library for date formatting and also it has other general functions such as number and string formatting which serves well in my code base.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just javascript to transform date to different locale:

first you will need to create date object with (new Date(yourdate)):

```
let date = new Date('10/30/2018');
```

then set date to specific locale use dash instead of underscore

```
date.toLocaleString('es-ES')
```

for your purposes you can just do:

```
new Date(data[0].originalDate).toLocaleString('es-ES')
new Date(data[0].expiryDate).toLocaleString('es-ES')
```

or do a map on entire data like this:

```
data.map(value => {
return { 
originalDate: new Date(value.originalDate).toLocaleString('es-ES'), 
expiryDate: new Date(value.expiryDate).toLocaleString('es-ES')
}
});
```

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

For all other advanced date manipulation I would suggest momentJS: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, learnt a new thing (date,toLocaleString). Though moment.js is a good javascript library, i'm going with sugar.js as it serves well in my case.